# Read CSV using header while ignoring some lines in JAVA

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to read CSV file using header. I am Using this code:

```
public String getSpecificCSVDataUsingHeader(String filePath, String header) {
        String value = "";
        String basePath = new File(filePath).getAbsolutePath();
        try (
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(basePath));
                org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(',').withHeader().parse(br);
         ) {
            for (CSVRecord record : parser) {
                value = record.get(header);
            }
            return value;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LogUtil.error(this, e.getMessage());
        }
        return value;
    }
```

it works perfectly for this kind of CSV (where the first line is header):
[image]

Now I wanted to read CSV with some lines before the actual header. like this one:
[image]

Is there any way where I could read csv using header while skipping the other lines. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know the number of lines that need to be skipped before the header?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality that skips lines that are not part of the CSV.

This must be a custom implementation as follows:

1. specify which one is the header
2. skip until that part
3. start your parsing

Answer (score 0):

Let me describe your problem. You need to skip the first n lines (except the header) in the CSV file and parse it. There isn’t a ready-to-use method in Apache Commons CSV library to skip the n lines. So you have to write your own Java code to do this.

It is simple to get it done using Java’s open-source package SPL. You just need one line of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =file("skip3lines.txt").read@n().to(4;).export().import@ct() |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as skiplines.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…

Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");

st = con.prepareCall("call skiplines()");

st.execute();

…
```

Or execute the SPL string within a Java program as we execute a SQL statement:

```
…

st = con.prepareStatement("==file(\"skip3lines.txt\").read@n().to(4;).export().import@ct()");

st.execute();

…
```